# error command webpack not found when I deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, npm, webpack, capistrano3

```
ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]
00:00 git:wrapper
  01 mkdir -p /tmp
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 2.312s
  Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-jec_access-production-jeanlinux.sh 100.0%
  02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-jec_access-production-jeanlinux.sh
✔ 02 root@157.230.93.52 1.210s
00:08 git:check
  01 git ls-remote git@bitbucket.com:jeanlinux/jecaccess.git HEAD
  01 02704634ef3fea8fb4ef983aa8a71b184f55f2cd       HEAD
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 4.701s
00:13 deploy:check:directories
  01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 0.721s
00:13 deploy:check:linked_dirs
  01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/log /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deploy/JecAcce…
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 2.250s
00:16 deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
  01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/config
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 1.022s
00:22 git:clone
  The repository mirror is at /home/deploy/JecAccess/repo
00:24 git:update
  01 git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.com:jeanlinux/jecaccess.git
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 1.063s
  02 git remote update --prune
  02 Fetching origin
✔ 02 root@157.230.93.52 3.030s
00:30 git:create_release
  01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 0.920s
  02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936
✔ 02 root@157.230.93.52 1.636s
00:36 deploy:set_current_revision
  01 echo "02704634ef3fea8fb4ef983aa8a71b184f55f2cd" > REVISION
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 2.451s
00:38 deploy:symlink:linked_files
  01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 1.233s
  02 rm /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/database.yml
✔ 02 root@157.230.93.52 2.587s
  03 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/config/database.yml /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/database.yml
✔ 03 root@157.230.93.52 0.893s
  04 rm /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/secrets.yml
✔ 04 root@157.230.93.52 1.192s
  05 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/config/secrets.yml /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/secrets.yml
✔ 05 root@157.230.93.52 4.403s
00:56 deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
  01 mkdir -p /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936 /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/tmp /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/public
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 1.101s
  02 rm -rf /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/log
✔ 02 root@157.230.93.52 0.852s
  03 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/log /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/log
✔ 03 root@157.230.93.52 1.158s
  04 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/tmp/pids /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/tmp/pids
✔ 04 root@157.230.93.52 3.071s
  05 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/tmp/cache /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/tmp/cache
✔ 05 root@157.230.93.52 0.942s
  06 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/tmp/sockets /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/tmp/sockets
✔ 06 root@157.230.93.52 0.727s
  07 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/public/system /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/public/system
✔ 07 root@157.230.93.52 1.159s
  08 ln -s /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/public/assets
✔ 08 root@157.230.93.52 1.433s
01:27 bundler:install
  01 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet
✔ 01 root@157.230.93.52 2.707s
01:33 deploy:assets:precompile
  01 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  01 Webpacker is installed  
  01 Using /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
  01 Compiling…
  01 Compilation failed:
  01 yarn run v1.13.0
  01 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
  01
  01 warning ../../package.json: No license field
  01 warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
  01 error Command "webpack" not found.
  01
```

> (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks) cap aborted!
>   SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host
>   157.230.93.52: rake exit status: 1 rake stdout: Webpacker is installed   Using
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/webpacker.yml
>   file for setting up webpack paths Compiling… Compilation failed: yarn
>   run v1.13.0 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for
>   documentation about this command.
>
> warning ../../package.json: No license field warning From Yarn 1.0
>   onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a
>   future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the
>   scripts. error Command "webpack" not found. rake stderr: Nothing
>   written
>
> Caused by: SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1 rake stdout:
>   Webpacker is installed   Using
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/webpacker.yml
>   file for setting up webpack paths Compiling… Compilation failed: yarn
>   run v1.13.0 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for
>   documentation about this command.
>
> warning ../../package.json: No license field warning From Yarn 1.0
>   onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a
>   future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the
>   scripts. error Command "webpack" not found. rake stderr: Nothing
>   written
>
> Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile (See full trace by running task
>   with --trace) The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while
>   executing on host 157.230.93.52: rake exit status: 1 rake stdout:
>   Webpacker is installed   Using
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/webpacker.yml
>   file for setting up webpack paths Compiling… Compilation failed: yarn
>   run v1.13.0 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for
>   documentation about this command.
>
> warning ../../package.json: No license field warning From Yarn 1.0
>   onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a
>   future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the
>   scripts. error Command "webpack" not found. rake stderr: Nothing
>   written
>
> ** DEPLOY FAILED
>   ** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
>
> DEBUG [5607bacb] Finished in 2.268 seconds with exit status 1
>   (failed).
>
> INFO [9d26f1fe] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle
>   install --path /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without
>   development test --deployment --quiet on 157.230.93.52
>
> DEBUG [9d26f1fe] Command: cd
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936 &&
>   /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development
>   test --deployment --quiet
>
> INFO [2c0ee907] Finished in 2.707 seconds with exit status 0
>   (successful).
>
> DEBUG [99f77c18] Running if test ! -d
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936; then echo "Directory
>   does not exist '/home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936'" 1>&2;
>   false; fi on 157.230.93.52
>
> DEBUG [99f77c18] Command: if test ! -d
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936; then echo "Directory
>   does not exist '/home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936'" 1>&2;
>   false; fi
>
> DEBUG [50cd673a] Finished in 2.866 seconds with exit status 0
>   (successful).
>
> INFO [407a8274] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle
>   exec rake assets:precompile on 157.230.93.52
>
> DEBUG [407a8274] Command: cd
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936 && ( export
>   RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
>   default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
>
> DEBUG [6bf4baca]       Webpacker is installed
>
> Using
>   /home/deploy/JecAccess/releases/20190210065936/config/webpacker.yml
>   file for setting up webpack paths
>
> DEBUG [6bf4baca]       Compiling…
>
> DEBUG [6bf4baca]       Compilation failed:
>
> yarn run v1.13.0
>
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about
>   this command.
>
> warning ../../package.json: No license field
>
> warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options
>   to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be
>   forwarded as-is to the scripts.
>
> error Command "webpack" not found.

Comment: execute 'yarn run webpack'

Answer (score 19):

You need to add this to the bottom of `config/deploy.rb`:

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Run rake yarn install"
  task :yarn_install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install --silent --no-progress --no-audit --no-optional")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Got this code from https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/deployment.md

Answer (score -2):

You need run task yarn install before assets:precompile.

Look at documentation

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/deployment.md